# Reactjs: How to pass user input from different files?

Tags: reactjs

I have a login page and inputs the email and password
I need the email reused on different pages like absent and news

How do I get the user inputted email from login and place it there?

Login.jsx
 function

```
   const { data } = this.state
        const tabletopModel = data['token']
        const newData = tabletopModel ? tabletopModel.all() : null
        console.log('log for newdata', newData)
        var c = 0;


        if (newData == null) {
            console.log('null')
        }
        else {

            for (var i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
                if (newData[i].アドレス == this.email.value && newData[i].Passkey == this.pass.value) {
                    c++;
                    //console.log('i', i);

                }

            }
            if (c > 0) {
                //success login
                document.getElementById("footerConfirmLogin").style.visibility = "visible";
                this.props.history.push({
                    pathname: '/Passkey',
                    email: this.email.value // your data array of objects
                })
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("footerConfirmError").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        }
```

and the email that's `<input type="email" name="username" ref={(email) => this.email = email} className="form-control" id="userEmail"/>` this is inside a form `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}`

I need to specifically place the value of email here

Absent.jsx

```
   render() {

        return (


<form className="gform" method="POST" action="asd">

<input type="text"  value= *the email value* />

</form>


        );
    }
```

Comment: You can pass the data down using props. But when child compoenent gets nested a deep level then it hard to mentain. You should take a look at the react context API or redux store.

Comment: i read it but im really struggling can u help me a bit? thanks

Comment: How your components are connected to each other? parent / child or siblings?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I'm not entirely sure how are they "connected" as parents / child

i think they're not 
i just move from "pages" using Route

Comment: is `this.email.value` giving you the correct email?

Comment: @Olufsen check my answer and let me know if it fits your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `email` is not a sensetive information, you can make use of [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

In your `Login` component you can store your `email` in `localStorage` when your `handleSubmit` method executes.

To store `email` in `localStorage` do this.

```
localStorage.setItem("email",this.email.value);  //considering `this.email.value` gives you correct value
```

And you can use this value wherever you want,

```
render() {
  const email = localStorage.getItem("email");
  return (
    <form className="gform" method="POST" action="asd">
      <input type="text"  value={email} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is what I need! 
but the `<input type="text"  value={email} />` returns blank

yes `this.email.value` captures the user input email

Comment: Try to print email. Also make sure after login success your localStorage gets value

Comment: Wow it works! 

This is super! i am able to get my email now
Thank you so much. I hope you have good days to come
Im gonna pass my subject now

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to do this would be by using [redux](https://redux.js.org) and [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) to create a central store to share data trough the entire app and create action creators to be able o trigger actions from any component that effects the central store.

You could also pass the email as props up and down the components that need to access it, but this gets very cumbersome over time.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding redux and react-redux

are there any example in passing the email as props
this is the last problem i need to solve in my assignment
thanks

Comment: this question is answered now
but I sure will remember your offer thank you